# way to have php header open same page but showing a hidden div?

Tags: php

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I am working on my first site and still learning. I am trying to add a captcha to the contact form taken from here http://www.captcha.net/ and using PHP.
At the moment it is working, but the code supplied on the site for it to work is as follows:

```
  <html>
    <body> <!-- the body tag is required or the CAPTCHA may not show on some browsers -->
      <!-- your HTML content -->

      <form method="post" action="verify.php">
        <?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>

      <!-- more of your HTML content -->
    </body>
  </html>
```

and the verify code for it on a different file (server side) is:

```
  <?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your_private_key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
  ?>
```

What I am wondering is if there is a way to have the if statement (if the captcha is wrong) open the contact page but show a hidden div displaying that the captcha code is wrong and try again.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: rather than using captcha you could have a normal text input with a style of display:none; and then on your submit page run an if statement to say if this text field is not blank dont do anything otherwise carry on. this is only for if you dont want to use captcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, You can try this way:

**verify.php**

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    header("Location: contact.php?show-error"); // replace by your file name
    exit;
}
else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
}
```

**contact.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['show-error'])){
    echo "<div>
        The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. 
        Go back and try it again.
    </div>";
}
```

Or:

```
<div style="display:<?php echo isset($_GET['show-error']) ? "block" : "none"; ?>">
    The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. 
    Go back and try it again.
</div>
```

But in your case, I think it's better to move `verify code` to contact page. So you can easy decide to show a message depend on if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the purpose of your "hidden div" idea is. Aren't you just providing users with a form to enter details and a captcha, and then when they submit you verify ALL their inputted data?  If all ok submit, else show errors and make them amend.

If so, could you not put the captcha code on your contact page?
If in the same file as your form, when user submits (PHP_SELF) you can run through the entire form data they sent checking what they inputted (`is_numeric()`, `strlen()`, etc) and then also check the captcha.
After all checks, if any errors at all, tell them where/what and they can try again.  Otherwise action the form (email you, store in DB, whatever).

You can then check the captcha on the same page:

```
if (!$resp->is_valid)
  {
    $CaptchaError = "error";
    // echo is invalid, reset form and make them try again
  }
else
  {
    $CaptchaError = "ok";
  }
```

If for whatever reason you need to captcha code in a separate file to your form, then just POST or set url vars GET or SESSION so when you send them back to wherever the captcha form is with header redirect, you have the data to serve them with the error notice.
Though processing this all on one page with POST data is usually the easiest and most manageable method.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing a die, take the message in a variable called $error. Based on isset($error) being true or false, you can make the div visible/hidden on the page load

Answer (score 0):

Inside the if statement (if the captcha is wrong), you could replace the error message with something like this:

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
header("Location: http://yoursite.com/contactformpage.php?error=captchaerror");
exit;
} else {
// Your code here to handle a successful verification
}
```

Just be sure to replace http://yoursite.com/contactformpage.php to whatever the actual URL to your contact form page is, but keep everything else (?error=captchaerror) as is.

Then on the contact form page you can have another if statement like this (put it wherever you want the error message to appear):

```
if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 'captchaerror') {
echo "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Please try again.";
}
```

If you have other possible 'error' scenarios you can change the "captchaerror" part of the url and repeat the steps above.

If you're not familiar with PHP $_GET variables, take a look at this page: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php